# Unable to Generate Dynamic Sitemap VUE 3 Laravel 9 VITE Project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, laravel-9, xml-sitemap

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import viteCompression from 'vite-plugin-compression';
import Pages from 'vite-plugin-pages'
import generateSitemap from 'vite-plugin-pages-sitemap'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
      vue({
        template: {
            compilerOptions: {
              isCustomElement: (tag) => ['marquee'].includes(tag),
            }
          }
        }),
        Pages({
          onRoutesGenerated: routes => (generateSitemap({ routes })),
        }),
        laravel({
          input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
          refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    optimizeDeps: {
      include: [
        'vue',
        'vue-router',
        '@vueuse/core',
        '@vueuse/head',
      ],
    },
});
```

Need to generate simple sitemap on public folder but unable to reach the target of the same.

I already tried with Vite-SSG-Sitemap & Vite-Plugin-Pages-Sitemap.

Plugins only generating the robots.txt file only.

Please help me out over the same.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried by importing 'routes' component in your router declaration?

```
// router/index.js
[...]
import routes from '~pages'

const router = createRouter({
[...]
```

Comment: yes i tried...but still not work....Any other solution to generate dynamic sitemap....?